# Detecting Memory Leaks in ActionScript-3 Project

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, memory-leaks

Is there any way to detect memory leaks in Flash ActionScript-3 project? what are the easier ways to achieve this in existing project ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First is to establish if you actually have a memory leak.  For that, I would recommend using a performance stat tool that gives you real-time feedback on your memory usage.

One of the best ones that I've used is [Mr. Doob's Stats](http://github.com/mrdoob) tool:

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [mrdoob.com](http://mrdoob.com/tools/stats/hires_stats2.png))</sub>

Just add it to the stage with

```
addChild( new Stats() );
```

And you'll be able to watch your memory usage in real-time.  Perform different actions to see what is causing the memory leak (is it just when you click on these buttons, or every frame, etc etc).

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion for Mr. Doob's Stats tool is a good one. Additionally if you are developing using flex builder professional you can use the built-in profiler. (your project does not have to be an actual flex project, you can develop pure as3 projects as well and still use the profiler)